# Database query on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

I had installed Zend Server CE in my laptop and i have tried to open my phpMyAdmin page via my email address but i got following message ie (#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server). what is the possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Error #1045 means that you have provided wrong username or password.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_access_denied_error

Comment: i have write the email address that i have typed in the beginning of the installation as the username. So do u think is there any wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

What have you already tried? Knowing nothing of that, here is what I would check:

- Is there a MySQL server installed?
- Is it running?
- Can you use the MySQL command-line client to connect to the MySQL daemon?

That last step prompts its own series of troubleshooting steps, which mostly boil down to "are you using the right username/password and does that user have appropriate permissions." If you don't know how to suss that out, you should do some more research.

Comment: I have installed MYSQL server during my installation but when i checked my extension status for MYSQL, its in OFF state. So do you think any clue from it?

Comment: That tells me the daemon is installed but not running. How you start it will depend on your OS; in e.g. Ubuntu you would use `sudo service mysql start`, and on a Mac you would install the MySQL control panel and click the button there.

Comment: Beats me, I don't do Windows.